# Accessing Graph API getting errors

Tags: iphone

I am facing one problem : i am using Graph API in my application. app working fine every time but there are displayed 3 errors , though there are errors app is running...

1) error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FbGraph", referenced from:

2) error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FbGraphFile", referenced from:

3) Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

for more information : I am using **XCODE 4.3.2**
what should i do to remove these errors ? need help...

Answer (score 0):

i think define linkers flag with -all_load if required the  -lstdc++, -ObjC, -lxml2....
and yes also check that Architecture define with these two armv6 and armv7.....
and then if its give error then define compiler with LLVM-GCC or LLVM and then restart app...
hope this help you..
:)